# Why is energy conservation apparently violated in this thought experiment?

Tags: electrostatics, energy-conservation, charge, batteries

I am no one to disprove the **law of conservation of energy**, but here is a thought experiment:

1. Assume that you are on the moon.
2. You have a positively-charged insulating sphere and two neutral conducting spheres.
3. Place the two neutral conducting spheres in contact with each other and place the positively-charged insulating sphere close by.
4. The positively-charged insulating sphere will cause separation of electrons between the two conducting spheres. One becomes negatively-charged and the other becomes positively-charged.
5. Slowly separate the two newly-charged conducting spheres.
6. Now you have a positive terminal and a negative terminal, and no effect on the positively-charged insulating sphere.
7. Use both terminals for energy and repeat.

Where does the additional energy come from?

Comment: The situation you describe does not violate conservation of charge at all.

Comment: Agree with Vincent. The title is misleading. I think you are questioning conservation of energy, no?

Comment: Hey, Now it's explaining what I wanted to. Sorry my bad...

Comment: Apart from the question in itself, you should not use emojis on stack exchange. Moreover, this is a place for problem solving and discussions. Using click-bait titles that have nothing to do with the question in itself is frowned upon and discouraged.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophorus

Comment: You separated two charges without work??

Comment: But it doesn't equate to the energy produced by the system. You can  assume +X to be much much High

Comment: And also Electrophorus talks about leaking the charges in the atmosphere. But I am on the moon.

Comment: Your lunar electrophorus is more efficient because it doesn't suffer losses due to charges leaking to the atmosphere.

Comment: @PM2Ring You're right, it does not. From the first version of this question it seemed to me this was a homework question. It has been modified to fit as a conceptual question. I have re-opened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to illustrate your steps. See the figure below which was taken from Physics Classroom website: https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-2/Charging-by-Induction

It describes your process but includes an important step missing from yours, namely, the need to remove the external positively charged object so as to free the localized negative charge on sphere A. Otherwise, the charge would remain bound (see diagram iii) rendering your electrostatic battery useless.

Three external actions are involved in creating the battery.

First, the electric field of the external positively charged object does work pulling electrons from sphere B to sphere A. See Diagram ii. Clearly energy needs to be supplied by the positively charged object to polarize the spheres.

Second, mechanical work has to be done by an external agent to separate the polarized spheres against the attractive force between them. see Diagram iii.

Third, mechanical work needs to be done by an external agent to move the positively charged external object away against its attraction to sphere A in order to free up the localized negative charge on sphere A (step iv). Otherwise, the battery would be useless. Another way to look at it is the presence of the external positively charged object effectively neutralize the localized negative charge of sphere A.

Although the above does not attempt quantify that the work done by the external agents that transfers energy to A and B equals the energy stored in them, I think it does clearly illustrate that external work is needed to create your two sphere electrostatic battery, just like external work is required to create a charged capacitor, which by the way is also effectively an electrostatic battery.

Since energy conservation is a fundamental law, I think it is up to you to to disprove that the energy transferred to the two spheres is less than the energy stored in them at the end of the process.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: But I don't think so, the work needed to separate is equal to the energy produced by the system.

Comment: And what if the spheres are large enough to create much more polarity between charges and what if the +X is much much more to separate the charges

Comment: As to your first comment, that's the point. Energy is conserved. The work done by the external agent equals the energy available from your created battery.

Comment: I meant that the work done needed to separate might **not** be equal to the energy that can be produced by the system

Comment: If you think it might not, why did you say equal? And why do you think it might not?

Comment: It might, in an imaginary world but it doesn't in the real one.  Anyway,  it's up to you to prove an extraordinary claim. And saying "what If" does not count as proof.

Comment: @nasu I assume your comment is addressed to the OP

Answer (score 3):

> Slowly separate the two newly-charged conducting spheres.

When you do this step, you apply an external force on these spheres and do mechanical work to move them apart. This transfers energy to the system from outside the system, and this is the source of the energy you are "creating".

Comment: Can this be ever **exactly** equal to the energy created by the system and what if the +X is much much greater value, and what if the spheres are much much larger to create much more potential difference b/w the spheres?

Comment: @RaghuvanshMani You are pulling unlike charges apart. Then, you are letting the unlike charges attract each other to get energy. These are exactly opposite processes. You are putting in the same energy you are getting out.

Comment: Ok, I am pulling unlike charges but am not using attraction to get the energy of any kind, and how I will?? I am using them to create the potential difference that will be used as batteries and repeating the same process will create ambiguity !!

Comment: The potential difference (and the field that it summarizes) is just another way of describing how two unlike charges feel an attractive force.